# How to full join two tables and return one column for joined field in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables like these:

```
Table A              Table B
+----------------+   +----------------+
|  id  | usage-a |   |  id  | usage-b |
|----------------|   |----------------|
|   1  |    v1   |   |   3  |    v5   |
|   2  |    v2   |   |   4  |    v6   |
|   3  |    v3   |   |   5  |    v7   |
|   4  |    v4   |   |   6  |    v8   |
+----------------+   +----------------+
```

And I want This:

```
Table A           
+--------------------------+   
|  id  | usage-a | usage-b |  
|--------------------------|   
|   1  |    v1   |   null  |
|   2  |    v2   |   null  |
|   3  |    v3   |    v5   |
|   4  |    v4   |    v6   |
|   5  |   null  |    v7   |
|   6  |   null  |    v8   | 
+--------------------------+
```

What should I do?
I tested "FULL JOIN" but it returns two columns for id with some null values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As both join columns have the same name, you can use the `using` operator in the join which does exactly that: remove the duplicate columns.

```
select *
from a
  full outer join b using (id);
```

```
c:\>psql postgres
psql (9.4.1)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=> create table a (id integer, usage_a text);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=> create table b (id integer, usage_b text);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=>
postgres=> insert into a
postgres-> values (1,'v1'), (2,'v2'), (3,'v3'), (4,'v4');
INSERT 0 4
postgres=>
postgres=> insert into b
postgres-> values (3,'v5'), (4,'v6'), (5,'v7'), (6,'v8');
INSERT 0 4
postgres=>
postgres=> select *
postgres-> from a full outer join b using (id);

 id | usage_a | usage_b
----+---------+---------
  1 | v1      |
  2 | v2      |
  3 | v3      | v5
  4 | v4      | v6
  5 |         | v7
  6 |         | v8
(6 rows)

postgres=>
```

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name, I think this way is better than first answer, is any difference on performance between  these two ways?

Comment: @Arshen: no, I don't think so.

Comment: @Arshen: This one is a bit faster, since the redundant column is removed from the result early and you save the `COALESCE` calls.

Answer (score 3):

Use `full outer join` :

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(A.id, B.id) AS id, 
    A.usage-a, 
    B.usage-b 
FROM 
    A 
 FULL OUTER JOIN 
    B USING(id)
```

Comment: But, Postgresql says "isnull function dose not exist"!